# How to AutoSearch from any part of a string and not from the beginning when user starts typing in a combobox?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I autosearch and find matches from any part of a string rather than from the beginning when user starts typing in a word in the combobox?

For eg. If user starts typing in "001007228" it should still display "GEM GRAVURECOINC - 001007228" as a narrowed down selection result. Else if user types "Gravure" it should still display "GEM GRAVURECOINC - 001007228" as a narrowed down selection from the list of values in a combobox.

It so happens that some users might remember part of the name or the numbers at the end at times.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement would use the `Like` operator, something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblSome WHERE FieldName Like '*" & Me!cboYourCombo & "*'"
```

The asterisks * are wildcard characters, which match any sequence of characters.

`Me` can only be used in the Form's Module, otherwise you would use `Forms!frmYours!cboYourCombo`, where `Forms` refers to all *open* forms.

Comment: How would I make it interactive? Which action event would I use?

Comment: You could use the `Change` event of the combobox, which happens for every character typed in the box.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! This is what I was expecting and worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trap the KeyPress event using VBA code in your database.

Press ALT-F11 to bring up the code behind the database and use something like this ..

```
Private Sub Combo2_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122 'alphachars only
            Combo2.ListIndex = FindIndex(Combo2.Value, KeyAscii)
        Case vbKeyDecimal
        Case vbKeyBack
        Case vbKeyRight
        Case vbKeyLeft
        Case vbKeyInsert
        Case vbKeyDelete
        Case vbKeyShift
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

Where 'cboYourCombo' is the actual object name of your actual combo-box control.

And inside the above subroutine trap the keystrokes that matter such as numbers and letters

This line ...

```
    Combo2.ListIndex = FindIndex(Combo2.Value, KeyAscii)
```

... is saying that it's trying to run a FindIndex() function (you have to write it) and it returns the location in the string where the character starts and then set the index in the combobox to start at that location. Actually this won't work, but you get the idea.

Well actually, you need to pass the entire list in the combobox to a routine that finds the location of the data you want in the FindIndex() function and return back the characters prior to the location you sought. In essence, you are telling the combobox to look from the left of the field to the right, but you already found the location of the data in the above routine.

ie.

Say we have this list ...

```
ABC123
ABC456
AHJ738
BHS238
MKJ299
```

If you code the above so that when ever you press a key, it goes and looks for the FIRST item in the above list that has that character. Lets say in this case the number 7.

When you press '7', the routine found the 'AHJ738' item and this happens to be the 3rd item in the list.

So it returns for you 'AHJ7' (at least) and this will trick the combobox to find it from the left of the field, if you know what I mean.

In other words, there is no pre-built method in the combobox control to seek out keystrokes in the middle of the text box. Unless you Google for alternative combobox controls that can do this, which are commercial variants.

Comment: Sounds good! But I have no clue of how the FindIndex() function needs to be implemented.